# How to mantain mp.isPlaying() state of android media player?

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

Hi friends I have an issue with Android media player. It is working but when I change the screen orientation, control with media player is lost, that is initially I am able to pause and stop the song, but once the screen orientation changes the song continues but I am unable to pause or stop etc.
This is the code I tried (I put the song in raw folder)

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_medial_player);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
playPause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
        playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mp.isPlaying()) {
                    if(mp!=null) {
                        System.out.println("*******");
                        mp.pause();
                    }
                } else {
                    if(mp!=null) {
                        System.out.println("#######");
                        mp.start();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

startSong= (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
        pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//              mp.pause();
                playSong();
            }
        });

stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);
        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.stop();
            }
        });
}


public void playSong() {
        try {
            mp.reset();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(MedialPlayer.this, resId);
            mp.start();
        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

In Manifest I use:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
```

Any help please...

Comment: check my answer !. It will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your API level ?

If your application targets API level 13 or higher (as declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), then you should also declare the "**screenSize**" configuration, because it also changes when a device switches between portrait and landscape orientations.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
```

Source : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: Hi spanjeta thanks for ur response, actually i had solve it by using,protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) and protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) these two method..and now its working prorerly...and also i am accepting ur answer as it is correct one..will check it later, thnks

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void Play(View v){
        final MediaPlayer md = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.test_cbr);

    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){ 
            if(md.isPlaying()) 
                    md.pause();

            else 
                    md.start();
        }

    }
    );
}
```